# maintaining reference to client files between sessions

Tags: javascript, html, video, local-storage

I'm developing a web app that works with video files -- specifically, I have the user 'select' their video file through a form input, I then construct a URL reference to that file, and set the `<video>` source to that URL. This allows me to work with user supplied content, without having to upload the video -- something that seems unnecessary, and will lead to decreased performance.

Here's my very simple code for now:

```
// within a change event for a file input
    var videoFile = e.currentTarget.files[0];
    var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(videoFile);
    var videoNode.src = fileURL;
```

This works great. The problem: It doesn't allow me to store a reference to this video in between user sessions. I've tried to save the fileURL into a Mongo document, and then later reload that video file... and while this works sometimes, it often breaks... with no clear consistency.

Does anyone have a good solution to storing reference to local files in between user sessions? Do I have to use something like the HTML5 Filesystem API? Localstorage?

Comment: hi, looking into the same thing, have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I may have missed what you are getting at, but it sounds like you just need a cookie.  http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

You can save whatever file name you want in a simple cookie and then the next time they visit the page you recall the video name they want.